# Is there a function to auto generate id code of qa on excel

Tags: excel

Is there a formula on excel that can be used to generate a custom ID and if I drag it down it automatically adds one to the row and, it should be permanent

this is for the form I am designing
       ="QA"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyymmdd")&TEXT(1, "000")

I expect the output of 
QA20190327001 or QA20190327002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `A1` use:

```
="QA"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyymmdd")&TEXT(ROW(),"000")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Note that the QA ID that's generated will change the next day. You'll need to change from the formula to hard-coded values if you need the IDs to stay (e.g. using "Paste as Values").

Comment: I want to autogenerate but the date and month will stay permanent

Comment: is there anyway the text will not change?

Comment: Well, easiest is to think about another way to make unique IDs, otherwise you might end up using VBA or just copy paste made IDs as text.